# iOS CollectionViewCell Expand Segue

Tags: ios, swift, uistoryboardsegue

How would I go about writing a custom segue (similar to iOS GroupOn app segue when you tap on a deal)?

Let's say I have 2 ViewControllers: FirstViewController & SecondViewController.

FirstViewController has a collectionview where each cell has an image and a label. When you tap on a cell, it goes to SecondViewController, which displays the information in detail. The image is at the top of SecondViewController, and details are below.

I'm wondering how to write the perform method and also how to write a custom animation for when the viewcontroller is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the animation between two ViewControllers, this is a good tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/110536/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions

There are also a number of transitions that you can use here: https://github.com/onmyway133/fantastic-ios-animation/blob/master/Animation/transition.md